# linux bash saved variable is empty

Tags: linux, shell

I'm new to shell. I try to get a string in file and use it to make a shortcut link.

tmp/tempfile.tmp

```
/mnt/sda5
```

in my test.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#working just fine!
echo  $(cat /tmp/tempfile.tmp | cut -d' ' -f2)

#empty result
USBdev = $(cat /tmp/tempfile.tmp | cut -d' ' -f2)
echo ${USBdev}/

# --making a link
ln -s ${USBdev} $(pwd)/C:
exit 0
```

why it is empty??

```
echo ${USBdev}  --result is empty!
```

I'm using this on my openwrt router.

I tried as follow, still empty

```
echo "$USBdev" 
echo "${USBdev%.*}"
```

**SOLUTION:**

REMOVE "SPACES" AROUND THE "=", thanks to **CDroescher**

change

```
USBdev = $(...)
```

to (remove spaces)

```
USBdev=$(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a shebang at the first line https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) and make sure that there are no spaces after and before "="

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#working just fine!
echo  $(cat /tmp/tempfile.tmp | cut -d' ' -f2)

#empty result
USBdev=$(cat /tmp/tempfile.tmp | cut -d' ' -f2)
echo ${USBdev}/

# --making a link
ln -s ${USBdev} $(pwd)/C:
```